# HTTP GET error is user invalid

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, get

I am using ASP.NET, in which I am receiving inquiries through verbs GET, the URL is special for this application.

The code works, but if the user sent a password invalidates http 200 Ok answer me, and in the body of the message "Fail user or pasword".

```
namespace WebApp_dev.Controllers
{

    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {


        [HttpGet]
        public string Save(string point)
        {

            // in point variable you will get part between /dev and /save
            // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 url it will be "point"

            // get parameters that follow by ? mark in url

            var queryParams = GetQueryParams(Request);
            string url_completa = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;

            int _indexPto = url_completa.IndexOf("/dev/");
            url_completa=url_completa.Remove(0, (_indexPto + 5));
           // _indexPto = url_completa.IndexOf("/");
            url_completa = url_completa.Remove(url_completa.IndexOf("/"), (url_completa.Length - url_completa.IndexOf("/"))); // tengo el nombre del punto en url_completa
            //--------------------------------------------------
            string url_query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
            _indexPto = url_query.IndexOf("&u=");
            url_query = url_query.Remove(0, _indexPto+1);
            string[] _User_pasw = url_query.Split(char.Parse("&"));//con esto queda la cadena separada el usuario y contraseña
            string _usuario, _pasword;
            _usuario = _User_pasw[0].Split(char.Parse("="))[1];
            _pasword = _User_pasw[1].Split(char.Parse("="))[1];
            bool _usuarioValido = UsuarioValido(_usuario, _pasword);



            if (_usuarioValido == false)
            {
            return "Fail user or pasword";
           }

            // loop through all of them
            foreach (var pair in queryParams)
            {
                string paramName = pair.Key;  // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be "name"
                string paramvalue = queryParams[pair.Key]; // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be 125.25

            AlmacenarValor(url_completa.ToString(), paramvalue, paramName);
            }

            return "OK: " + url_completa.ToString();
        }

        private bool UsuarioValido(string _usuario, string _pasword)
        {
            MonitoreoEntities _context = new MonitoreoEntities();
            PuntoDeMedicion _pdm = _context.PuntoDeMedicion.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Nombre == _usuario && a.Contrasena == _pasword);
            if (_pdm == null)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        } 

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetQueryParams(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {

            return request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                         .ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value,
                              StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
     public static void AlmacenarValor(string _dispositivo, string _valor, string _parametro)
    {

        MonitoreoEntities _context = new MonitoreoEntities();
        PuntoDeMedicion _puntoDeMedicion = _context.PuntoDeMedicion.Include("EntradaSalida").Where(a => a.Nombre == _dispositivo).FirstOrDefault();
        foreach (EntradaSalida _entradasalida in _puntoDeMedicion.EntradaSalida)
        {
            if (_entradasalida.Etiqueta == _parametro)
            {
                Registro _registro = new Registro()
                {
                    EntradaSalidaId = _entradasalida.Id,
                    FechaHoraCreacion = DateTime.Now,
                    FechaHoraRegistro = DateTime.Now,
                    PuntoDeMedicionId = _puntoDeMedicion.Id,
                    Valor = decimal.Parse(_valor)
                };
                _context.Registro.Add(_registro);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using Advanced REST client for Google Chrome:

Response user Ok (pasword ok)

```
200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 8723
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Response headers 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Expires: -1 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJveWVjdG8gdGVsZW1ldHJpYVxTZXJ2ZXJcV2ViQXBwX2RldlxkZXZccHJ1ZWJhMTIzXHNhdmU=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 22:23:01 GMT 
Content-Length: 28 
Raw
JSON
Response
Word wrap Copy to clipboard Save as file
```

> **" OK: list123"**

Responce user pasword invalid

```
200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 1415
Request headers 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Response headers 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Pragma: no-cache 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
Expires: -1 
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJveWVjdG8gdGVsZW1ldHJpYVxTZXJ2ZXJcV2ViQXBwX2RldlxkZXZccHJ1ZWJhMTIzXHNhdmU=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 22 Sep 2014 22:30:14 GMT 
Content-Length: 18 
Raw
JSON
Response
Copy to clipboard Save as file
```

> **"Fail user or pasword"**

It is programmed in this way, it works correctly, I would like to change this message and send HTTP 409 Conflict if the user or pasword is incorrect and http 200 Ok is correct.

**thank you very much for your reply**

I get a series of errors, being the variables in another context:

*

> _usuarioValido
>   url_completa

*

As I can do to pass it from one context to another.
The code remained as follows:

```
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {


        [HttpGet]
        public string Save(string point)
        {

            // in point variable you will get part between /dev and /save
            // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 url it will be "point"

            // get parameters that follow by ? mark in url

            var queryParams = GetQueryParams(Request);
            string url_completa = Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
            // Busco el nombre del punto de medicion-----------
            int _indexPto = url_completa.IndexOf("/dev/");
            url_completa=url_completa.Remove(0, (_indexPto + 5));
           // _indexPto = url_completa.IndexOf("/");
            url_completa = url_completa.Remove(url_completa.IndexOf("/"), (url_completa.Length - url_completa.IndexOf("/"))); // tengo el nombre del punto en url_completa
            //--------------------------------------------------
            string url_query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
            _indexPto = url_query.IndexOf("&u=");
            url_query = url_query.Remove(0, _indexPto+1);
            string[] _User_pasw = url_query.Split(char.Parse("&"));//con esto queda la cadena separada el usuario y contraseña
            string _usuario, _pasword;
            _usuario = _User_pasw[0].Split(char.Parse("="))[1];
            _pasword = _User_pasw[1].Split(char.Parse("="))[1];
            bool _usuarioValido = UsuarioValido(_usuario, _pasword);



            if (_usuarioValido == false)
            {
        return "Usuario invalido";
           }

            // loop through all of them
            foreach (var pair in queryParams)
            {
                string paramName = pair.Key;  // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be "name"
                string paramvalue = queryParams[pair.Key]; // for /dev/point/save?name=125.25 will be 125.25

            AlmacenarValor(url_completa.ToString(), paramvalue, paramName);
            }

            return "SUCCESS OK de: " + url_completa.ToString()+"\n";// mando el ok, tiene que llevar el  fin de linea.
        }

    [HttpGet]
    [ResponseType(typeof(String))]
    public HttpResponseMessage Save(HttpRequestMessage request, string point)
    {

    if (_usuarioValido == false)
    {
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Fail user or password");
    }

   return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, url_completa.ToString()); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(String))]
public HttpResponseMessage Save(HttpRequestMessage request, string point)
{
    .......
    if (_usuarioValido == false)
    {
        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Fail user or password");
    }

    .......
    return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, url_completa.ToString()); 
}
```

I have not tested the code above, but roughly the concept is there.

Hope it helps.

Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much for your reply
I get a series of errors, being the variables in another context:

_usuarioValido
  url_completa